Is there a way to have multiple users on the same device without anyone being the same person with Webauthn in Django?
I am currently working on a project in Django. The application in question consists of allowing agents to register their presence at guard posts (guarding) and to make the rounds. Per post, we can have 2 or 3 agents and who will have to share the same device (Smartphone or tablet)
To ensure that each agent is actually present, I wanted to use Webauthn (fingerprints) in the application. So after connecting using the identifiers of the Django connection form, they will have to authenticate using Webauthn to be able to register their arrival at the post. Naturally, each agent would have been registered by their fingerprints at the very level of the security parameters of the device upstream
My question is whether this is possible with a shared device. Agents may want to help each other by passing their Django login credentials, so if authentication by Webauthn can cause Agent B to fail to login pretending to be Agent A.
Thanks to the kind souls who will do me the honor of answering me.
My codes already allow registration and authentication with webauthn.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If the system is akin to a digital timecard where someone "punches in/out" via their id and fingerprints and you record this activity as an event, why would there be any issue with an arbitrary number of users do such a thing. Once they "punch in" you don't maintain an open session tied to that user right?

The question is fine, even if the bot has complained. Doing this directly in Webauthn wont work, you'd need something on the shared phone that could match a given fingerprint towards a given private key and only to that private key, which neither WebAuthn or CTAP is capable off directly from the specification. If you are able to set the phone up to support fingerprint matching specific keys, this would be doable.

@JonSG
Thank you for your answer, in fact, the agents (guards) who monitor the post will have to share the smartphone or tablet to record their activity (taking up duty, going down, doing the rounds) and each should do it without doing the same as the other. That is to say that agent A cannot record the presence for example for agent B while the latter is actually absent.

@Asthor
Thanks for your feedback, indeed, I will think about activating the "multi-user" feature, I believe that this will allow to isolate the fingerprints of each user in his account and like that, Agent X could not pass himself off as Agent Y. Now, I will have to limit the authentication of the popup to fingerprints only and deactivate the password case if possible. I will explore this avenue.
